# Null Hypothesis in Repeated Measures Study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

I am designing an uncontrolled, prospective study (one group) with continuous outcome variables, which will be measured at 3 points in time (i.e., baseline, timepoint_1, timepoint_2).

If the null hypothesis for a simple pre/post study is that there is no difference between the mean "pre" score and the mean "post" score, what is the null hypothesis for a study with more time points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null is that *the means are the same at all three time points*, and this is tested with a repeated measures ANOVA.

Comment: Thank you. If I conduct a repeated-measures ANOVA and the p-value is significant, what test would I conduct to determine where the difference is?

Comment: @Maldini That might warrant its own question.

Comment: @Dave Is there a resource to help me determine whether a question should be its own question (v. a follow-up question)? I'm a newbie here and don't want to just post a multitude of individual, but related questions. Thanks!

Comment: On the contrary, I would say that the way Cross Validated (and probably most or all of the other Stacks) works is that it is beat to ask multiple questions. // There’s a way to take the tour that introduces you to Cross Validated, which you might consider doing. I think you even get a badge for it.

Comment: As always, if this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted, and optionally upvote it.